# How do I utilize both Coldfusion and Jquery Syntax highlighting in VScode?

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-code, coldfusion, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to code in Coldfusion and jQuery in VScode with the Coldfusion, Adobe Coldfusion Builder, and jQuery Code Snippets extensions. I'm trying to get the syntax highlighting to play nice with each other. The issue arises when I call any id element at the head section for jquery. Since it uses a single hash symbol the extension throws an invalid token error and highlights the rest of the code as a comment.

Here's an example:

```
<cfoutput>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
    
    <!-- bunch of coldfusion code -->
    
    <script <!-- jQuery CDN here --> > </script>
    <script>
</cfoutput>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#submitButton").click(function(){ <!-- token error here everything below is highlighted brown-->

            alert("Hello World!");

            });
        });

    </script>
<cfoutput>
 </head>
 <body>

    <cfset buttonMessage = 'Click me!'>
    <button button type="button" id='submitButton'> #buttonMessage# </button>

 </body>
</cfoutput>
```

Is there any way to continue proper syntax highlighting after the token error? Instead of squeezing all my jQuery scripts up at the top before any CFoutput tags?

Tried turning off coldfusion extensions. That just turned off all my syntax highlighting. Seems like the only way is to put all jQuery scripts nefore any cfoutput tags.

Comment: The standard I've used at all of my recent CF jobs was never to have inline JavaScript or CSS. It's best to move them to their own `.js` or `.css` files for caching and other reasons. If you need to use the value of a CF variable in your JavaScript, you can make that value an attribute of a hidden form field (referenced by DOM ID) or have a small list of inline JS variables specifically for that purpose. Having an external JS file will allow the editor to better format the code and give you insight into your JS that you'll not get when writing JavaScript in a file w/ another extension.

Comment: If thats the case, alot of devs at my job are doing it wrong haha, the source codes are littered with inline JS, Thanks for the advice, I'll try to refactor my code to have proper seperation of concerns, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me awhile but I figured it out. Wrapping the jQuery code AS WELL as the jQuery CDN source with cfoutput closing and opening tags solved the problem for me.

```
<cfoutput>
 <head>

    <!-- bunch of coldfusion code -->

    </cfoutput>
    
    <script <!-- jQuery CDN here --> > </script>
    
    <cfoutput>

     <!--- bunch of coldfusion code -->

    </cfoutput>
    <script>

     <!-- jQuery code here -->

    </script>
    <cfoutput>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</cfoutput>
```